# Images from my storage uploads are not showing PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, storage, public

After setting up my profile page my uploaded images initially produced an image on my local host. However lately it shows up as an icon instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp0Yt.png

I should note I am using php 7.3.19

**profiles/index.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 p-5">
            <img src="{{ $user->profile->profileImage() }}" class="rounded-circle w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 pt-5">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3">
                    <div class="h4">{{ $user->username }}</div>

                    <follow-button user-id="{{ $user->id }}" follows="{{ $follows }}"></follow-button>
                </div>

                @can('update', $user->profile)
                    <a href="/p/create">Add New Post</a>
                @endcan

            </div>

            @can('update', $user->profile)
                <a href="/profile/{{ $user->id }}/edit">Edit Profile</a>
            @endcan

            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="pr-5"><strong>{{ $postCount }}</strong> posts</div>
                <div class="pr-5"><strong>{{ $followersCount }}</strong> followers</div>
                <div class="pr-5"><strong>{{ $followingCount }}</strong> following</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pt-4 font-weight-bold">{{ $user->profile->title }}</div>
            <div>{{ $user->profile->description }}</div>
            <div><a href="#">{{ $user->profile->url }}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row pt-5">
        @foreach($user->posts as $post)
            <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                <a href="/p/{{ $post->id }}">
                    <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100">
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Is there an issue in the way I am picking it up from the storage?
I used 'php artisan storage:link'

**create.blade.php**

```
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @csrf

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 offset-2">

                    <div class="row">
                        <h1>Add New Image</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Caption</label>

                        <input id="caption"
                               type="text"
                               class="form-control{{ $errors->has('caption') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                               name="caption"
                               value="{{ old('caption') }}"
                               autocomplete="caption" autofocus>

                        @if ($errors->has('caption'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('caption') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Image</label>

                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                        @if ($errors->has('image'))
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row pt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**PostsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use  App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $users = auth()->user()->following()->pluck('profiles.user_id');

        $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->with('user')->latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
        $image->save();

        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'caption' => $data['caption'],
            'image' => $imagePath,
        ]);

        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }

    public function show(\App\Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }
}
```

**ProfilesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Profile;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        $follows = (auth()->user()) ? auth()->user()->following->contains($user->id) : false;

        $postCount = Cache::remember(
            'count.posts.' . $user->id,
            now()->addSeconds(30),
            function () use ($user) {
                return $user->posts->count();
            });

        $followersCount = Cache::remember(
            'count.followers.' . $user->id,
            now()->addSeconds(30),
            function () use ($user) {
                return $user->profile->followers->count();
            });

        $followingCount = Cache::remember(
            'count.following.' . $user->id,
            now()->addSeconds(30),
            function () use ($user) {
                return $user->following->count();
            });

        return view('profiles.index', compact('user', 'follows', 'postCount', 'followersCount', 'followingCount'));
    }
    //($user = (User::findOrFail($user));)
    //('user' => $user)
    //

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);

        return view('profiles.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);

        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'url' => 'url',
            'image' => '',
        ]);

        if (request('image')) {
            $imagePath = request('image')->store('profile', 'public');

            $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1000, 1000);
            $image->save();

            $imageArray = ['image' => $imagePath];
        }

        auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge(
            $data,
            $imageArray ?? []
        ));

        return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}");
    }

    public function show($user_id)
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user_profile = Profile::info($user_id)->first();
        return view('profiles.show', compact('profile', 'user'));
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }

}
```

Comment: what does `$user->profile->profileImage()` return?

Comment: It returns the image provided by the user;                                                            
public function profileImage()
    {
        $imagePath = ($this->image) ? $this->image : 'profile/JNiNHZYPax0bk1mZWBDuZbvKfghk7OsZRJjsTrXO.png';

        return '/storage/' . $imagePath;
    }

Comment: if you use the network inspector are they coming up as 404s?

Comment: Yes actually it is

Answer (score 0):

Use `asset` helper function to get the uploaded image URL.

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $post->image) }}" class="w-100">
```

OR

```
<img src="{{ asset(Storage::url($post->image)) }}" class="w-100">
```

Comment: None of these work, do you think it could be because I installed NPM

Comment: No, NPM does not affect it. Can you check if the images getting stored correctly in the linked directory(\storage\app\public)? If possible share the store function code.

Comment: How do i find the store function code, the most i get is (\storage\app\public/profile) (\storage\app\public/uploads)

Comment: Store function code as in, the controller function(Form action) which you have used to add an image in the filesystem.

Comment: Hmm i've added the instances of code that used it in the create form and postController

Comment: Replace `$image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);` with `$image = Image::make(public_path(Storage::url($imagePath)))->fit(1200, 1200);`

Comment: It is now returning (Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found)

Comment: Include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` on top of the file. Please refer Laravel documentation

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick either :/ it worked before and its just recently started giving me these errors

Comment: Is this `(Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found)` error fixed? It should be fixed with the above code as it is part of the core.

Comment: That error corrected itself now its returning (Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException) currently having a fall out with the code

Comment: Check if the path generated by `public_path("storage/{$imagePath}")` exists. Also, check if the current user has permission to access the file from that path.

Comment: I think the image is that page in particular, i've tried to 'upload a file' it went into my storage however it is not displaying on the webpage. (sorry i've taken so long, i've been undergoing chemo and i've been out of it)